# Strange behaviour of css controlled footer in template on some pages

Tags: html, css

I have edited a footer in a template based website (all the pages should be build on the same structure right?)

But for some reason I can't find, the footer is displayed not at the bottom.

Maybe the whole footer thing doesn't work at all and was I lucky because of the long content??

**This pages look ok:**

[page1](http://www.friesecomputerservice.nl/onze-services.html)
[page2](http://www.friesecomputerservice.nl/laptop-reparatie.html)

**These don't look ok**

[Page1](http://www.friesecomputerservice.nl/openingstijden.html)
[Page3](http://www.friesecomputerservice.nl/contact-gegevens.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the problem the whitespace between the footer and the content?

If so, removing the following declaration should do the trick:

```
#content 
{
   min-height: 550px;
}
```

Just be aware that on pages without much inside the `#content` div the contact area will overlap the footer when clicked.

Comment: Hurray! you lead me to the solution. When changing the min-height to min-height:622px; you force the content div to be atleast 622px high. Am I wrong and will this work on other browsers?

Comment: Yes, min-height forces an element to be at least the height specified, even if its contents do not fill the space.  W3Schools makes the claim that it is supported by all major browsers (http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_dim_min-height.asp).  Quirks mode reveals that only versions of IE prior to 7 have limited support (http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html)

Comment: well,i think that's god enough. Ie 6 is I think 10 years old, people should start to get over it. :)

Comment: Ok, but what if the document height is taller than 622px? I'm looking at the pages on resolutions > 1024x768 and I see a gap between the footer and the document bottom. May not matter, just commenting :P

Answer (score 1):

It's related to the height of the document. The `body` tag is only as tall as the point where your footer ends, the white gap beneath it is still the `html` element, but there's not enough content within your `body` tag to extend the page to the bottom of your browser, like pages 1 and 2.

This is a restriction of the way your template system is created, there's ways of solving this (http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/ for example) but these may be out of your control. I'd like to say that overriding the body element's `height` CSS property would work for you, but I don't think it does anyway.